# Compiled with CX_FREEZE, Beautiful Soup program wont run in Console

Tags: python, web-scraping, cx-freeze, beautifulsoup

This is the error I am getting when I run the EXE file of the program. The program runs fine in Pycharm but generates such error in console. **bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a Tree Builder with features you requested. Do you need to install a parser library?**

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["bs4, urllib, requests"], "excludes": [""]}
base = None

setup(  name = "Weather",
        version = "0.9.0",
        options = {"program": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("program.py", base=base)])
```

And the program.py is a usual script scraping a simple site.

Comment: I'm not familiar with [tag:cx-freeze], but is the comma-separated string as single element in a list intentional, or did you mean writing a list of strings?

Comment: You need a parser library, this link shows they had to add both lxml and gzip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348774/whats-needed-to-get-beautifulsoup4lxml-to-work-with-cx-freeze#31391904